# Designing a single WebViewController to load number of url's iphone

Tags: iphone

I have a view which consists of 5 buttons. On clicking each button the corresponding url must open up.

I want to design a single webviewcontroller to load the corresponding url on button click... Can anyone suggest how to achieve this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you will modally show the web view upon click of one of the buttons you can pass the URL to the controller which you create before you show it modally.

Something like this

```
MyWebViewController *controller = [[MyWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyWebView" bundle:nil];
controller.URL = <here goes the URL according to the button>
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
[controller release];
```

URL needs to be a synthesized instance variable of MyWebViewController. Inside MyWebViewController you can then use the URL.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you link the buttons to their corresponding methods correctly this will work. I just chose random pages to link to as an example...

In the WebviewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface WebViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

NSString *urlAddress;
NSURL *url;
NSURLRequest *requestObj;

- (IBAction)google:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)mySite:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)wzor:(id)sender;
- (void)gotoAddress;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

In the WebViewController.m file:

```
#import "WebViewController.h"


@implementation WebViewController

@synthesize webView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)google:(id)sender {
    urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSLog(@"urlAddress: %s", [urlAddress cStringUsingEncoding:1]);
    [self gotoAddress];
}

- (IBAction)mySite:(id)sender {
    urlAddress = @"http://www.zahorikfamily.com/casey";
    NSLog(@"urlAddress: %s", [urlAddress cStringUsingEncoding:1]);
    [self gotoAddress];
}

- (IBAction)wzor:(id)sender {
    urlAddress = @"http://www.wzor.net";
    NSLog(@"urlAddress: %s", [urlAddress cStringUsingEncoding:1]);
    [self gotoAddress];
}

- (void)gotoAddress {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    NSLog(@"gotoAddress");
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```